# Manual gcd function in Haskell using pattern matching

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

---

Haskell beginner here! I'm solving a practice problem where I'm trying to make a manual gcd function using the pattern matching concept so far I've tried the following:

```
myGcdPM :: Int -> Int -> Int
myGcdPM x 0 = x
myGcdPM x y = myGcdPM y (mod x y)
```

The code seems to work but I'm trying to understand if this is a proper PM and a valid solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look up [the source of the standard implementation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Real.html#gcd) (if you didn't know where to find that: [ask Hoogle](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=gcd)), you'll find that it's almost the same as yours:

```
gcd x y         =  gcd' (abs x) (abs y)
                   where gcd' a 0  =  a
                         gcd' a b  =  gcd' b (a `rem` b)
```

Well, the definition of interest is really `gcd'`:

```
gcd' a 0  =  a
gcd' a b  =  gcd' b (a `rem` b)
```

The only difference to yours is that it uses `rem` instead of `mod` (but on positive inputs these behave the same) and that it writes this in infix notation (`` a `rem` b `` is the same as `rem a b`).

Then, `gcd x y = gcd' (abs x) (abs y)` just wraps the whole thing, ensuring that the inputs are nonnegative.